# Some SVG symbols not visible in browser

Tags: css, html, svg, symbols

I'm using a generated SVG file with symbol declarations, and my page will only show the first symbol in the sheet.  Trying to figure out how to get all the symbols to display, using the following syntax:

```
<svg role="img" class="icon icon-code" title="Icon: HTML Brackets">
    <use xlink:href="icons.svg#code"></use>
</svg>
```

Here's a test case: http://plnkr.co/edit/oSG6bdeK6AHrdfUyBTop?p=info

And here's a successful example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46814417/svgtest/index.html

Comment: I have a [Python solution](http://pastebin.com/RiXH4NNn) to the [question you just deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735170/match-a-string-containing-a-comma-in-a-comma-delimited-list) about breaking up a comma delimited string using regex. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load your icon.svg file into your browser, you get an error reported.  For instance, in Chrome it says:

```
error on line 8 at column 87: Namespace prefix sketch for type on path is not defined
```

Your second symbol has an attribute with a "sketch:" namespace.  That namespace is not defined anywhere.  If you remove this attribute I expect your test will start working.

Comment: Nailed it. Just added svgmin to my build process and everything's back to normal. Nice catch!